# Function file_get_content don't work occasionally

Tags: php

When I am using a `file_get_content` to download result of php script execution:

```
    //mainfile.php
    $ctx = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'timeout' => $this->cfg['gp_timeout']/2
            )
        )
    );
    $url_xml='http://test.server.eu/webgatescript.php?getphoto&param1=1&test=1&param2=2&param3=3';
    $webgateResponse=file_get_contents($url_xml,false,$ctx);
```

As I know, function `file_get_content` returns `string` - content of file, if file is not exist returns `FALSE`.

From time to time function `file_get_content` returns `FALSE`, despite I am in 100% sure that remote file returned content (xml file in my case, I have access and logs). Furthermore `file_get_content` returns `FALSE` few microsecond after end of execution remote script, but it takes less time then timeout was setted.

Part of logs:

```
10:22:04<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
10:22:16<response><htlName/><lang/><texts/></response>
10:22:46<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
10:22:58<response><htlName/><lang/><texts/></response>
10:23:28<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
10:23:29<response><htlName/><lang/><texts/></response>
10:23:59<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
10:23:59<response><htlName/><lang/><texts/></response>
10:24:29<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
10:24:29<response><htlName/><lang/><texts/></response>

Warning: file_get_contents(http://test.server.eu/webgatescript.php?getphoto&param1=1&test=1&param2=2&param3=3): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  in /home/www/mainfile.php on line 22

Call Stack:
    0.0002      93616   1. {main}() /home/www/mainfile.php:0
      175.5346     109072   2. file_get_contents(string(172), bool, resource(14) of type     (stream-context)) /home/www/mainfile.php:22

10:24:5910:25:46<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
10:25:47<response><htlName/><lang/><texts/></response>
```

I made some tests, one of them was running file `mainfile.php` in `exec` (I have both files on this same test server, but on production server that will be two separated systems)

```
    exec("php webgatescript.php >> tom2.log");
```

and everyone case of running `webgatescript.php` is logging.

Comment: Have you tried without timeout ? `$webgateResponse=file_get_contents($url_xml);`

Comment: Do you show all warnings? When returning FALSE, file_get_contents can also fire warnings that tell you more about what happened.

Comment: All of theese test was making using this same url address in while(TRUE) loop, so every time request URL is exactly the same, and answear olso is (if is returned by file_get_content).

Comment: @gd1: Yes, I do. Even I used `$http_response_header` variable to display response header, response code was 200, but I first time used this wariable and I have no sure that this variable showing header about this `file_get_dontent` request

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: Yes, this same result.

Comment: @Skamielina then you should try with cURL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on `file_get_contents`.

A lot of (shared) webservers don't allow `file_get_contents` to fetch files from other servers, but do allow the use of [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

```
$url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';

// start cURL
$ch = curl_init($url);

// set options (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4); // four seconds until connect timeout
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // we want the response in a variable
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4); // four seconds until timeout

$response = curl_exec($ch); // get contents

curl_close($ch); // close the cURL handle
```

It's not easy, but is very reliable.

---

I (probably) found the answer! As I mentioned, you can set an option that allows or disallows `file_get_contents` (and some other functions) to get files from an URL.

I have found the [Filesystem and Streams Configuration Options](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php). The `allow_url_fopen` setting can be used to allow or disallow opening URL's using `fopen`, which applies to `file_get_contents` too. It should be enabled on default, so I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Either way, I'm still pro-cURL ;)

Comment: Do you have any proof to backup your claims that cURL is "more reliable"? I am using file_get_contents with http stream wrappers for years now with no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for that, works well, so it must be problem with `file_get_contents` function... And one more question: `file_get_contents` uses HTTP communication protocol, so should be good golution between different servers. Why wrote you that it is not?

Comment: @Gordon The only proof I have is experience. Shared webservers often don't allow cross-server `file_get_contents`, but do allow the use of cURL. It just depends on the server configuration.

Comment: @Skamielina if it worked for you, please mark my answer as correct by pressing the big outlined "V" left of the answer. Your answer rate will rise, making people answer your questions better.

Comment: @Gordon I have edited my answer, explaining why I discourage the use of `file_get_contents` without marking it as "unreliable".

Comment: @TimS. thanks. The OP's host allows fetching content from remote locations though, so suggesting cURL is still only curing the symptom but not the cause. I'll revoke the dv though.

Comment: I have modified my post, mentioning the actual setting in php.ini that allows or disallows `file_get_contents` to fetch URL's. That could cause (and resolve) the issue.

Comment: I used CURL and now I didn't notice that `curl_exec` returned `FALSE`, except the timeout was reached (that's correct). But I am considering about `file_get_contents` function, and reason of FALSE status, while server responded correctly... Maybe it depends of additional header `timeout` parameter. I'd notice also that if I put for example 30s in `timeout` the waiting for response will not end at 30s , but is doubled (60s)...